Excel VBA to Word string replacement
I have a code snippet that pulls the data from my Excel workbook into an array and then populates the list within a Word document. There are multiple lists within the document and each has a unique placeholder. The code runs perfectly well for 5 out of 6 lists, but for some reason mashes all arrays together into the 2nd list. A snippet of the code below:
    ' Loop through each row in ManagerArray
    For row = LBound(ManagerArray) To UBound(ManagerArray)
        ' Replace placeholder with ManagerArray row content
        wdoc.Content.Find.Execute FindText:="<<ManagerCriteria>>", ReplaceWith:=ManagerArray(row), Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
        ' Insert new line and placeholder after the replaced content if it's not the last row
        If row < UBound(ManagerArray) Then
            wdoc.Content.Find.Execute FindText:=ManagerArray(row), ReplaceWith:=ManagerArray(row) & vbCr & "<<ManagerCriteria>>", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End If
    Next row

    
    ' Loop through each row in BRArray
    For row = LBound(BRArray) To UBound(BRArray)
        ' Replace placeholder with BRArray row content
        wdoc.Content.Find.Execute FindText:="<<BRCriteria>>", ReplaceWith:=BRArray(row), Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
        ' Insert new line and placeholder after the replaced content if it's not the last row
        If row < UBound(BRArray) Then
            wdoc.Content.Find.Execute FindText:=BRArray(row), ReplaceWith:=BRArray(row) & vbCr & "<<BRCriteria>>", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End If
    Next row

    
    ' Loop through each row in AIMArray
    For row = LBound(AIMArray) To UBound(AIMArray)
        ' Replace placeholder with AIMArray row content
        wdoc.Content.Find.Execute FindText:="<<AIMCriteria>>", ReplaceWith:=AIMArray(row), Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
        ' Insert new line and placeholder after the replaced content if it's not the last row
        If row < UBound(AIMArray) Then
            wdoc.Content.Find.Execute FindText:=AIMArray(row), ReplaceWith:=AIMArray(row) & vbCr & "<<AIMCriteria>>", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End If
    Next row

    
    ' Loop through each row in EISArray
    For row = LBound(EISArray) To UBound(EISArray)
        ' Replace placeholder with EISArray row content
        wdoc.Content.Find.Execute FindText:="<<EISCriteria>>", ReplaceWith:=EISArray(row), Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
        ' Insert new line and placeholder after the replaced content if it's not the last row
        If row < UBound(EISArray) Then
            wdoc.Content.Find.Execute FindText:=EISArray(row), ReplaceWith:=EISArray(row) & vbCr & "<<EISCriteria>>", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End If
    Next row

    
    ' Loop through each row in SEISArray
    For row = LBound(SEISArray) To UBound(SEISArray)
        ' Replace placeholder with SEISArray row content
        wdoc.Content.Find.Execute FindText:="<<SEISCriteria>>", ReplaceWith:=SEISArray(row), Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
        ' Insert new line and placeholder after the replaced content if it's not the last row
        If row < UBound(SEISArray) Then
            wdoc.Content.Find.Execute FindText:=SEISArray(row), ReplaceWith:=SEISArray(row) & vbCr & "<<SEISCriteria>>", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End If
    Next row

    
    ' Loop through each row in VCTArray
    For row = LBound(VCTArray) To UBound(VCTArray)
        ' Replace placeholder with VCTArray row content
        wdoc.Content.Find.Execute FindText:="<<VCTCriteria>>", ReplaceWith:=VCTArray(row), Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
        ' Insert new line and placeholder after the replaced content if it's not the last row
        If row < UBound(VCTArray) Then
            wdoc.Content.Find.Execute FindText:=VCTArray(row), ReplaceWith:=VCTArray(row) & vbCr & "<<VCTCriteria>>", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End If
    Next row

The codes are all the same, except for the placeholder and corresponding array. The issue occurs with the BRArray replacement - I have debug printed it and it is showing the correct list in the immediate window. If I move any of the following arrays around, it will always happen to whatever replacement happens 2nd in the code. Any ideas on what could the issue be?
Tried separating the replacement part into a separate subroutine, but this did not solve the issue.

When does this error occur: in your initial replaces or in the If row < UBound(BRArray) case? You may use a join of the array instead of looping through it.

Make it easier on yourself in two ways.

The first is to DRY - don't repeat yourself. You mentioned pulling the common code into a separate function, which is an excellent idea.

The second is to simplify how you're replacing the placeholder with the array data.


The example below shows an efficient method. As tested, it doesn't hiccup on multiple arrays/placeholders.
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim mgrArray As Variant
    mgrArray = Split("first line,second line,third line,fourth line,last line", ",")
    
    Dim theWordApp As Word.Application
    Set theWordApp = AttachToMSWordApplication
    theWordApp.Visible = True
    
    Dim theDoc As Word.Document
    Set theDoc = theWordApp.Documents.Open("C:\temp\test.docx")
    
    CopyArrayToDoc mgrArray, "<<ManagerCriteria>>", theDoc
       
End Sub

Sub CopyArrayToDoc(ByRef theArray As Variant, _
                   ByVal tag As String, _
                   ByRef theDoc As Word.Document)
    '--- create the replacement multi-line string
    Dim newText As String
    Dim arrayRow As Long
    For arrayRow = LBound(theArray) To UBound(theArray)
        newText = newText & theArray(arrayRow) & vbCr
    Next arrayRow
    
    '--- replace the placeholder with the multi-line string
    theDoc.Content.Find.Execute FindText:=tag, _
                                ReplaceWith:=newText, _
                                Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub

Public Function AttachToMSWordApplication() As Word.Application
    '--- finds an existing and running instance of MS Word, or starts
    '    the application if one is not already running
    Dim mswApp As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set mswApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        '--- we have to start one
        '    an exception will be raised if the application is not installed
        Err.Clear
        Set mswApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    Set AttachToMSWordApplication = mswApp
End Function

